# Removing class from breadcrumb when user click on previous tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs, breadcrumbs

Class is added when user click on tabs next tab and any tab but now i need remove class="tbcb" when user click on and previous tab. Like when i click on all tabs and then i click on 4th or 1st tab change the color of breadcrumb green to grey for all next breadcrumb with active or previous breadcrumb.

```
// breadcrumb code is here
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
        var target = $(e.target).addClass('fn'); // activated tab
        if(target.hasClass('fn')){
            target.closest('.tab-link').find('#tbcp').addClass('tbcb');
            //alert("success");
        }else{
            target.closest('.tab-link').css('display' , 'none');
        }
    });
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/pod4fob1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly then I think you need this behavior:

https://jsfiddle.net/pod4fob1/7/

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
   var target = $(e.target).addClass('fn'); // activated tab

   if ($(".tbcb").length < $(".tab-link").length) {
     target.closest('.tab-link').find('#tbcp').addClass('tbcb');
   } else {
     var index_1 = target.closest('.tab-link').index();

     $(".tab-link:gt(" + index_1 + ")").each(function() {
       $(this).find('#tbcp').removeClass('tbcb');
     });

   }

 });
```

Comment: thanks for your best effort. but i need your bit more help. 
when i click on all tabs after this i click on 3rd tab then 4th or 5th breadcrumb is UN-selected. continuously when i click on 1st or 0 tab nothing happen will you please solve this problem.

Comment: So in simple words: if we are on 4th tab (irrespective of whether we have completed all tabs previously or not) and try to go on lower number tab then all the other higher tabs should get marked as un complete. Is this statement correct?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the current element using $(this) then get it's parent and search inside the parent for your divs using the div class, like this

```
<div class="boxwrap">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="button" id="button1">Go</a>
    <div class="boxwrap_inner noDisplay" id="content1">
        Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
<div class="boxwrap">
    <a href="javascript:;" class="button" id="button2">Go</a>
    <div class="boxwrap_inner noDisplay" id="content2">
        Content goes here
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    $(this).parent().find(".boxwrap_inner").slideToggle(200);
});
```

you can check a working example forked from your fiddle on this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/mn6khese/